# Cannot edit post after posting as a guest

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

There is a self answer here [How can I keep audio in Windows 8.1 from fading in when I start playing a sound file?](https://superuser.com/questions/783277/how-can-i-keep-audio-in-windows-8-1-from-fading-in-when-i-start-playing-a-sound#comment1018963_783277)

The OP states

> I asked this as a guest but when I answered the email to set up the account it seperated somehow so I don't know how to get back to that guest account again (glitch in the guest-to-user algorhythm).

Not sure if it is a bug or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, the user asked the question as a guest and lost access to the cookie. The user's then registered and posted the not-an-answer comment.

With no cookie, there's no way to validate that the 2 users are the same(if it was, now that would be a bug).

There's an option under [Contact](https://superuser.com/contact) page to request user profile merge, the user should follow those instructions